# WebGrid MVC3 renders as string instead of Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm using `MVC3 WebGrid`, and got this simplest `cshtml`, that won't work

```
@model IEnumerable<MyNamespace.MyClass>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);
}
@grid.GetHtml()
```

But this code, **do** work

```
@model IEnumerable<MyNamespace.MyClass>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);
}

@MvcHtmlString.Create(grid.GetHtml().ToHtmlString())
```

**Question:** The first and simpler code renders as string instead of Html... what could possibly make the first code to fail, and obligates me to use the second way?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your code, even running it locally works fine. Can you post your MyClass code. You are not running some kind of encoding module like AntiXss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently someone who went through the project didn't know `MVC` already takes care of html characters rendered in the View...

We had in `Web.Config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="MyNamespace.Views.MyViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        ...
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

And `MyViewPage` was messing around some Helpers and other linstructions like Html.Raw